# "Will be like" or "would be like"?

Tags: grammar

> I'm making wild guesses about what the future would/will be like.

Is either legitimate? If so what's the differences in meaning?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The three sentences below demonstrate correct use of would/will in your situation:

- I am making guesses about what the future will be like.
- I was making guesses about what the future would be like.
- I am making guesses about what the present would be like if you we knew how to cure AIDS.

Comment: Don't we need "to" for "like"? e.g. I was making guesses about what the future would be like "to". Or, I was making guesses about to what the future would be like.

Answer (score 2):

You would use *will* if you meant only that you wondered about the future in general, given no other conditions.

You would use *would* if you presented a hypothetical scenario along with your general state of wonder.

> I wonder what the future would be like if the Republicans were to take the 2012 presidential election.

But if you consider the conditional to be a *fait accompli* you could say

> I wonder what the future will be like when the Republicans take the 2012 presidential election.